# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

Tags: ajax, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Такая проблема: код аякса отрабатывается некорректно, а именно в консольку выбивается ошибка:  `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS`, и при этом HTML-документ, согласно скрипту, не изменяется, НО запрос уходит.

Код аякса:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function send()
{
//Получаем параметры
var id = $('#id').val();
var pass = $('#pass').val();
  // Отсылаем паметры
       $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "public/auth.php",
                data: "id="+id+"&pass="+pass,
                // Выводим то что вернул PHP
                success: function(html) {
 //предварительно очищаем нужный элемент страницы
                        $("#response").empty();
//и выводим ответ php скрипта
                        $("#response").append(html);
                }
        });

}

</script>
```

Как можно решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Виталий RS, тут три варианта:

1. Виноват кэш. Лечится простым `ctrl+F5`
2. Виноват AdBlock. Лечится сменой классов элементов без использования `ad`, `banner` и тому подобных имен или полным отключением аддона.
3. Это внутренний баг Chrome из разряда "вводящие в заблуждение сообщения об ошибках". Иными словами, на самом деле, никакой ошибки нет.
   Баг был исправлен в 40й версии, [доступной в dev и canary версиях браузера, начиная с 25 октября 2014 г.](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=424599#c17) , а начиная с 3-его декабря 2014 г. и в бета версии.

Подробнее на `stackoverflow`:
[Bizarre Error in Chrome Developer Console - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408931/bizarre-error-in-chrome-developer-console-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-ca)

Comment: Спасибо, вылечил следующим образом: стал генерировать число от 1 до 99999, и отправлять вместе с запросами, как итог - всё стало нормально обрабатываться.